# How can I set an if statement when all the items in a list of lists equal one value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I am trying to program a scenario where when a every value within a list of lists are the same.

In this case, here is what my list would initially look like.

```
value = []
for i in range(10):
    value.append([])
    for j in range(10):
        value[i].append(0)
```

This creates a list that looks like this: (the part of it anyway)

```
>>> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0...
```

I then have it randomized in a certain way, random values changing to 1 to show a state change.

so it would look like:

```
>>> [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1...
```

So here is what I want to do.
When every value in each of these lists are changed back to 0, I want some way to identify that they are all equal to 0.

In such a way it could be used like an if statement, so that when all of them are 0, it will trigger something to happen, such as carry out another function caused by this.

I thought about using the `all()` function, but that seems to not work so well:

```
if all(i=True in range(all(j==0 in value[i][j]))): 
    if all(i==0 for value[j] in value for j in value)
```

Comment: Where's your doesn't work code? It would be little helpful.

Comment: @KevinGuan I tried things like this:        
    `if all(i=True in range(all(j==0 in value[i][j]))):`  and          
    `if all(i==0 for value[j] in value for j in value)`

Comment: The first one of those has an assignment where it would cause a syntax error, no `for` (possibly another syntax error), and a non-iterable in a call to `all()`. It's not even close to making sense. The second one is way off as well. I recommend taking a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little creative:

```
if '1' not in repr(list):
```

Of course, this is not part of the `for` loop. But it is one of the most efficient ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use `all()`:

```
if all(item==0 for item in sublist):
```

Or you could use a `set`:

```
if set(sublist) == {0}:
```

If you're looking for when every sublist in the entire structure is `0`, that would look like this:

```
if all(item==0 for sublist in structure for item in sublist):
```

Or this:

```
if {item for sublist in structure for item in sublist} == {0}:
```

Comment: I really enjoy the wording of "item for sublist in structure for item in sublist"

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Wait I'm sorta confused, in this case would sublist be my value list?  or would that be a structure?  Or is a sublist typed like say: value[i][j]

Comment: `structure` is the whole thing, `[[0, 1,...], [1, 0,...], ...]`. The `sublist` is each of the nested objects, `[0, 1,...]`, taken one at a time.